# Как передать параметры в ajax запросе к php скрипту

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

***Как мне передать параметры в ajax запросе к php скрипту***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add_ads').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax/ajax.php?id=1',
    })
    .done(function (data) {
      alert(data);
    });
});

<button id='add_ads'>add</button>
```

`url: 'ajax/ajax.php?id=1'` нужно что б рaботало, хром пишет ошибку: `jquery.min.js:5 POST http://rufilm.ua/admin/ajax/no_add_ads.php?id=1 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`
как это исправить?

P.S Буду благодарен....

Comment: Так подключите библиотеку `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: я подключил, забил в код добавить....

Comment: не понял что значит `я подключил, забил в код добавить`?

Comment: я укоротил код в сообщение, что б не вдавать в подробности

Comment: ну хоть сделайте скрин ошибки а то так и гадать научимся)))

Comment: AdBlock включен?

Comment: да, AdBlock включен

Comment: виключу, спасибо

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!!!

Comment: кстати, как тут поднять репутацию тому, кто помог?

Comment: Razmik Galstyan, знаю , я ж написал текст ошибки....

Comment: @Ostap34PHP За ответы можно голосовать, а если ответ на твой вопрос можно и птичку поставить за одно.

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan понял, спасибо

Comment: В POST запросе данные передаются не через URL, а в теле запроса. Если вам нужно именно в URL то шлите GET, если нет - читайте документацию https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/